# Airdropping Solana to a Specific Account

Tags: rust, blockchain, solana, solana-cli, anchor-solana

I would like to **airdrop sols into a specific account** to get my smart contract to fire an anchor test. Whenever I run my test I come across the error `Error: Account BdFchxtKbEaWtsbuFX2nbKyZCjhz5LN8vyPukQzJQrME has insufficient funds for spend (1.30250136 SOL) + fee (0.000945 SOL) There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(ExitStatus(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.`

The error is self-explanatory but how do I airdrop tokens to that specific account, I can run `solana airdrop 5` but then it airdrops it to another account GgRbD2AdibdAtBrQMJJEooco9gKt48Sd98Gn7vZQ1nJK.

I even tried transferring the tokens from one account to another using `solana transfer BdFchxtKbEaWtsbuFX2nbKyZCjhz5LN8vyPukQzJQrME 5 --allow-unfunded-recipient` but the transaction is just hanging.

Below is my smart contract in Rust using Anchor:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::system_program;

declare_id!("BNDCEb5uXCuWDxJW9BGmbfvR1JBMAKckfhYrEKW2Bv1W");

#[program]
pub mod solana_twitter {
    use super::*;
    pub fn send_tweet(ctx: Context<SendTweet>, topic: String, content: String) -> ProgramResult {
        let tweet: &mut Account<Tweet> = &mut ctx.accounts.tweet;
        let author: &Signer = &ctx.accounts.author;
        let clock: Clock = Clock::get().unwrap();

        if topic.chars().count() > 50 {
            return Err(ErrorCode::TopicTooLong.into())
        }

        if content.chars().count() > 280 {
            return Err(ErrorCode::ContentTooLong.into())
        }

        tweet.author = *author.key;
        tweet.timestamp = clock.unix_timestamp;
        tweet.topic = topic;
        tweet.content = content;

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SendTweet<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = author, space = Tweet::LEN)]
    pub tweet: Account<'info, Tweet>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub author: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(address = system_program::ID)]
    pub system_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Tweet {
    pub author: Pubkey,
    pub timestamp: i64,
    pub topic: String,
    pub content: String,
}

#[error]
pub enum ErrorCode {
    #[msg("The provided topic should be 50 characters long maximum.")]
    TopicTooLong,
    #[msg("The provided content should be 280 characters long maximum.")]
    ContentTooLong,
}
```

And below is my test in Typescript:

```
import * as anchor from '@project-serum/anchor';
import { Program } from '@project-serum/anchor';
import { SolanaTwitter } from '../target/types/solana_twitter';
import * as assert from "assert";
import * as bs58 from "bs58";

describe('solana-twitter', () => {
    // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
    anchor.setProvider(anchor.Provider.env());
    const program = anchor.workspace.SolanaTwitter as Program<SolanaTwitter>;

    it('can send a new tweet', async () => {
        // Call the "SendTweet" instruction.
        const tweet = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
        await program.rpc.sendTweet('veganism', 'Hummus, am I right?', {
            accounts: {
                tweet: tweet.publicKey,
                author: program.provider.wallet.publicKey,
                systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
            },
            signers: [tweet],
        });

        // Fetch the account details of the created tweet.
        const tweetAccount = await program.account.tweet.fetch(tweet.publicKey);

        // Ensure it has the right data.
        assert.equal(tweetAccount.author.toBase58(), program.provider.wallet.publicKey.toBase58());
        assert.equal(tweetAccount.topic, 'veganism');
        assert.equal(tweetAccount.content, 'Hummus, am I right?');
        assert.ok(tweetAccount.timestamp);
    });

    it('can send a new tweet without a topic', async () => {
        // Call the "SendTweet" instruction.
        const tweet = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
        await program.rpc.sendTweet('', 'gm', {
            accounts: {
                tweet: tweet.publicKey,
                author: program.provider.wallet.publicKey,
                systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
            },
            signers: [tweet],
        });

        // Fetch the account details of the created tweet.
        const tweetAccount = await program.account.tweet.fetch(tweet.publicKey);

        // Ensure it has the right data.
        assert.equal(tweetAccount.author.toBase58(), program.provider.wallet.publicKey.toBase58());
        assert.equal(tweetAccount.topic, '');
        assert.equal(tweetAccount.content, 'gm');
        assert.ok(tweetAccount.timestamp);
    });

    it('can send a new tweet from a different author', async () => {
        // Generate another user and airdrop them some SOL.
        const otherUser = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
        const signature = await program.provider.connection.requestAirdrop(otherUser.publicKey, 1000000000);
        await program.provider.connection.confirmTransaction(signature);

        // Call the "SendTweet" instruction on behalf of this other user.
        const tweet = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
        await program.rpc.sendTweet('veganism', 'Yay Tofu!', {
            accounts: {
                tweet: tweet.publicKey,
                author: otherUser.publicKey,
                systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
            },
            signers: [otherUser, tweet],
        });

        // Fetch the account details of the created tweet.
        const tweetAccount = await program.account.tweet.fetch(tweet.publicKey);

        // Ensure it has the right data.
        assert.equal(tweetAccount.author.toBase58(), otherUser.publicKey.toBase58());
        assert.equal(tweetAccount.topic, 'veganism');
        assert.equal(tweetAccount.content, 'Yay Tofu!');
        assert.ok(tweetAccount.timestamp);
    });

    it('cannot provide a topic with more than 50 characters', async () => {
        try {
            const tweet = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
            const topicWith51Chars = 'x'.repeat(51);
            await program.rpc.sendTweet(topicWith51Chars, 'Hummus, am I right?', {
                accounts: {
                    tweet: tweet.publicKey,
                    author: program.provider.wallet.publicKey,
                    systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
                },
                signers: [tweet],
            });
        } catch (error) {
            assert.equal(error.msg, 'The provided topic should be 50 characters long maximum.');
            return;
        }

        assert.fail('The instruction should have failed with a 51-character topic.');
    });

    it('cannot provide a content with more than 280 characters', async () => {
        try {
            const tweet = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
            const contentWith281Chars = 'x'.repeat(281);
            await program.rpc.sendTweet('veganism', contentWith281Chars, {
                accounts: {
                    tweet: tweet.publicKey,
                    author: program.provider.wallet.publicKey,
                    systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
                },
                signers: [tweet],
            });
        } catch (error) {
            assert.equal(error.msg, 'The provided content should be 280 characters long maximum.');
            return;
        }

        assert.fail('The instruction should have failed with a 281-character content.');
    });

    it('can fetch all tweets', async () => {
        const tweetAccounts = await program.account.tweet.all();
        assert.equal(tweetAccounts.length, 3);
    });

    it('can filter tweets by author', async () => {
        const authorPublicKey = program.provider.wallet.publicKey
        const tweetAccounts = await program.account.tweet.all([
            {
                memcmp: {
                    offset: 8, // Discriminator.
                    bytes: authorPublicKey.toBase58(),
                }
            }
        ]);

        assert.equal(tweetAccounts.length, 2);
        assert.ok(tweetAccounts.every(tweetAccount => {
            return tweetAccount.account.author.toBase58() === authorPublicKey.toBase58()
        }))
    });

    it('can filter tweets by topics', async () => {
        const tweetAccounts = await program.account.tweet.all([
            {
                memcmp: {
                    offset: 8 + // Discriminator.
                        32 + // Author public key.
                        8 + // Timestamp.
                        4, // Topic string prefix.
                    bytes: bs58.encode(Buffer.from('veganism')),
                }
            }
        ]);

        assert.equal(tweetAccounts.length, 2);
        assert.ok(tweetAccounts.every(tweetAccount => {
            return tweetAccount.account.topic === 'veganism'
        }))
    });
});
```

**Update**
Simply airdropping to the specific account helped, `solana airdrop 3 <Account Address>`. Another related problem was that my local cluster was hanging, to resolve this I followed the steps below:

1. Checked if local chain was running ps au
2. killed local solana-test-validator process
3. Cleaned out the workspace cargo clean
4. Deleted node_modules rm -rf node_modules
5. Reinstalled node modules yarn install
6. Re-ran tests anchor test

Answer (score 5):

first of all, try to ensure that the provider section of your anchor.toml set to testnet like this

```
[provider]
cluster = "testnet"
wallet = "/home/yourname/.config/solana/id.json"
```

also, use this command to set cluster for testnet

```
solana config set --url https://api.testnet.solana.com
```

check active account in your solana running node with

```
solana address
```

it should show your running node active account public key

also, check account balance with

```
solana balance
```

and if you don't have enough sol to run your test or deploy(after test) you can airdrop sol by running

```
solana airdrop 2
```

the point is trying to airdrop 2 sol at a time(multiple times)

now you can run the anchor test again(after anchor build)

Comment: Additionally, you can specify an airdrop recipient by running `solana airdrop 1 BdFchxtKbEaWtsbuFX2nbKyZCjhz5LN8vyPukQzJQrME`: https://docs.solana.com/cli/usage#solana-airdrop

Comment: Thank you! That worked, I had to restart my solana-test-validator and then run the command above. My transaction was hanging and am not sure why that was happening.

Comment: as error noticed: Account has insufficient funds for spend (1.30250136 SOL) + fee (0.000945 SOL) There was a problem deploying. so airdrop some sol and there we go

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the url when airdropping. I think max you can airdrop 2

```
solana airdrop 2 2QdQZvax3uzxRWc58PR4weAX4e1AZb3c9Wfn5NtzK7Sb --url devnet
```

If this hangs or fails that is because solana devnet server is going down very often. Visit this https://api.devnet.solana.com/

and click on `What's the status of this server?` if server is down you will see error message

[image]

if not you see `200 Ok` message

Answer (score 0):

For running Anchor tests:

```js
    const user1KP = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

    let token_airdrop = await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(user1KP.publicKey, 
       10 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);

    const latestBlockHash = await provider.connection.getLatestBlockhash();
    await provider.connection.confirmTransaction({
      blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
      lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
      signature: token_airdrop,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Anchor.toml

```
[provider]
cluster = "Localnet"
wallet = "~/.config/solana/id.json"
```

When running unit tests using the 'anchor test' command，modify the Anchor.toml file and set the cluster to 'Localnet', there will be no error message stating  "has insufficient funds"